# python decrement and possible deletion in one statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python, I wonder if there is a combined statement for the following

```
# dct = defaultdict(int)
dct[k] -= 1
if dct[k] == 0:
    del dct[k]
```

Or any arbitrary lower bound, if below, delete the element.

Comment: You could define a subclass that implements this behavior. But I'm not sure that that would be the best design, since it would run against the [Principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) and the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Such a type wouldn't be usable anywhere a `dict` would be. And I think most people would find it surprising if `dct[k] = v` only _sometimes_ sets the key `k`

Comment: I'd recommend defining a standalone class (not a dictionary subclass) to capture this behavior, and use some well-named methods instead of `__getitem__`/`__setitem__`

Comment: what if i know what i am doing and just want to write some hack code to achieve the goal? i want to see how flexible it is in python to achieve this goal; when not to consider these best-practice design principle(s).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that such type of datastructure exist, but you can simply create your function for this purpose:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def decrement_or_delete(dct, key, lower_bound=0):
    dct[key] -= 1
    if dct[key] <= lower_bound:
        del dct[key]
```

And afterwards:

```
dct = defaultdict(int)
k = 'some_key'
dct[k] = 2


decrement_or_delete(dct, k)
decrement_or_delete(dct, k)

print(dct)
```

Will output empty dict.

Why do you need the specific function for this purpose?

Comment: found it to occur quite commonly in my code. I wonder if we can simply monkey-patch defaultdict or the dict to achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can't monkey-patch `dict` nor `defaultdict`, because it'll error with

```
ERROR!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
TypeError: cannot set '...' attribute of immutable type 'dict'
```

What you can do is maybe subclass `defaultdict` overriding the behavior you want:

```
import collections

class mydefaultdict(collections.defaultdict):
    def __init__(self, factory):
        super().__init__(factory)
        self._factory = factory
    
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
        if value == self._factory():
            super().__delitem__(key)

dct = collections.defaultdict(int)
dct['a'] = 1
dct['a'] -= 1
print('a' in dct)  # should output False, outputs True

dct = mydefaultdict(int)
dct['a'] = 1
dct['a'] -= 1
print('a' in dct)  # outputs False
```

Please note this is an ad-hoc implementation and you might need to implement some corner cases.